# passing style as argument to jquery animate

Tags: jquery, animation

so i have a function for handling elements with a hover, however i want to be able to pass in the css styles as an argument.  i have tried different variations, but this is currently my code (just the necessary portion)...

```
function load_hovers(mouseOverCss){
  $('.hover').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
      eval(mouseOverCss)
    }, 500, function() {
    });
```

and i call `load_hovers("backgroundColor: 'red'");`

this returns an error `invalid object initializer $(this).animate({`.  without using `eval`, the error is `missing : after property id {eval(mouseOverCss)}\n`.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it.

```
var mouseOverCss = {};
mouseOverCss['backgroundColor'] = 'red';
mouseOverCss['paddingLeft'] = '100px';
load_hovers(mouseOverCss);
```

and then just

```
$(this).animate(mouseOverCss, duration);
```

thanks Phil for getting me on the path of not just sending a string pre-formatted for animate()!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better to stay away from the Eval option (Eval is evil and all that...) and try passing in an object to your method instead.

First create an object for your CSS argument:

```
var css = {};
css.Property = 'backgroundColor';
css.Value = 'Red';
```

Then you can pass this (or an array of them, if you need multiple properties) to your method:

```
function load_hovers(classes)
{
    $('.hover').hover(function(){
      $(this).animate({
        $(this).css(classes.Property, classes.Value); // or iterate over an array of these
      }, 500, function() {
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: this method still generates a `missing : after property id` error for me.

Comment: How and where are you calling this method?  Is it inside a jQuery DOM ready event?

Comment: yes it is inside a ready event, i just left that out of the code i posted to keep it short.